# Adding run/debug configuration environment variables to a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, environment-variables

I am trying to add Environment Variables to my Run/Debug Configurations in my flutter project in Android Studio but the field is greyed out and I have no idea how to otherwise create environment variables. Any ideas how to add them either this way or in some other way?

[A picture of my Run/Debug cConfigurations where the Environment variables are greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlvnU.png)

Comment: You should create different flavors for your project and then add respective flavor to Build Flavor option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A not-recommanded way to do this is to edit the `flutter` file(a script file: unix: bash, windows: bat). [see here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/bin)
I'm using linux and I have a problem of the application scale (since I'm using a hidpi screen), the probablly easist way to solve the problem is to set the environment variable `GDK_SCALE=2`. After some struggling, I finally edit my flutter source file like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
# Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
# found in the LICENSE file.

export GDK_SCALE=2
# ---------------------------------- NOTE ---------------------------------- #
#
# Please keep the logic in this file consistent with the logic in the
# `flutter.bat` script in the same directory to ensure that Flutter continues


# ... [content omitted] ...
```

If you want to make environment variable change when starting a new project, please consider `before launch` option in `RUN confiugration`, you can run other configurations before run the current configuration. The ideal running sequence is running `delete environment variable lines` configuration(Shell Script type), before which execute(before launch) `flutter run` configuration, before which execute(before launch) `add environment variable lines` configuration(Shell Script type).(Total 3 configuration files which are linked in order) It should also show flutter debug window, since this option exists in the `flutter run` configuration.

Other ways I have tried:

1. set global environment(all the application scale changed)
2. modify android studio desktop file(android studio size changed)
3. hack android studio run configuration (like $(export x=1) to execute command, however failed)